# How to Update Mysql Data with a button on Home Page that is passing id on URL?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, ajax

I have created an Edit Item popup Bootstrap modal on home page. Now what I want is to update the selected item details using the PHP.

**Here i am passing item id through the URL in order to select the item**

Now when I press edit Button it opens a Popup with all the details in it( already filled) but when I try to click on Save Changes Button it just do nothing and My data not updated. I have also used POST method but its not working.

**Here is the Button that opens the Popup Modal**

```
<?php 
$res= mysqli_query($db,"SELECT* FROM `books`;");

if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
  while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if($row!=0)
    {
    $bid= $row['book_id'];
 ?>
<ul>
<li>
 <a onclick="$('#editModal<?php echo $row['book_id']?>').modal('show');" class="btn-show-modal edit-btn" data-toggle="modal"><i style="padding-right: 140px;" class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
</li>


<!--Here is the Popup Modal for Edit -->

<div id="editModal<?php echo $row['book_id']?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit This Book</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="updatebook.php" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="isbn" class="col-form-label">ISBN</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['isbn'];?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="col-form-label">Enter Book Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="author" class="col-form-label">Enter Author Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" value="<?php echo $row['author'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Image URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description" class="col-form-label">Enter Book Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" value="<?php echo $row['description'];?>"></textarea>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="url" class="col-form-label">Book URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" value="<?php echo $row['url'];?>"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <a href="updatebook.php?id=<?php echo $row['book_id']?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save Changes</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php 
}
}
}

else
{
   echo"<h1 style='color: white;font-size:58px; font-family: Poppins; font-weight: 600;' class=m-2>U!Oh Nothing Found Here!</h1>
<button onclick=\"window.location.href='add_books_form.php'\" class=\"btn btn-info bg-primary m-5\">Contribute</button>";
 }
?>

</ul>
```

**Here is the updatebook.php Page**

```
<?php

include "connection.inc.php";

if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $id= $_POST['id'];
    $isbn= $_POST['isbn'];
    $title= $_POST['title'];
    $author= $_POST['author'];
    $image= $_POST['image'];
    $desc= $_POST['description'];
    $url= $_POST['url'];

$res = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE books SET isbn= '$isbn', title= '$title', author= '$author',image= '$image', description= '$desc', url= '$url' WHERE book_id= '$id'");
?>
if($res) 
{
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        alert("Data Updated Successfully"); 
        window.location.href= "home.php";
    </script>
}
else
{
    <script>
    alert("Not Updated!");
        window.location.href="home.php";
    </script>
}
<?php
}
?>
```

Please Help me to solve this Update Issue i am facing for a long time. I have researched all through but didn't got any solution.

Comment: Don't know why I am not able to update the item. Please Help!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Why have you wrapped your "Save" button in a hyperlink? That makes no sense. It will cause a GET request, but your PHP expects a POST. it isn't submitting your form properly. Get rid of the a href, turn the button into type="submit" and try again. Any PHP/HTML forms tutorial would show you the standard way to structure a form, including the submit button. I'm not sure why you decided to take a different approach.

Comment: @ADyson Okay, let me check

Comment: The "Save" button. That's the only one wrapped in a hyperlink as far as I can see!

Comment: Now changing button type= "submit" is not working. Clicking over "save changes" is not working anymore.

Comment: Did you remove the hyperlink too? Show your new code in the question. Also "not working" isn't a useful description of anything. Explain specifically what happened

Comment: I have changed this 
        `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save Changes</button>`

Comment: @codewithdev the submit button is not in form as well

Comment: That's an excellent point.  move the button inside the form. Again, every forms tutorial in the world would show it like that already.

Comment: Also you need a (hidden?) field for `id` so it will be submitted with the rest of the form data.

Comment: I have placed my form closing tag correctly but still its not working. And whenever i try to click on "save changes" button it just prompt dialog for "ok" then for a millisecond an error coming on `updatebook.php` stating that `if($res){.......` something and then home page opens.

Comment: So, remove the window.location stuff for the moment, and then you might see the error. And/or configure PHP to log errors and warnings to a file.

Comment: @ADyson So Its the error `Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\E-library\home\updatebook.php on line 7
if($res) { } else { }`

Comment: Anyway actually... it's not just an error, it's just showing you the exact text your page outputs to the screen. The `if $res` is outside your PHP tags...so it's not seen as real code, just static text

Comment: If you want more help, you'll need to update the question to show the latest version of your code, since we don't know what exact changes you have made overall. Details matter, as we've just observed.

Comment: The undefined index is a warning rather than an error btw. But certainly the fact the value is missing will mean the query doesn't update anything. the answer below shows you how to use the hidden field properly.

Comment: It's working perfectly Now. Thanks @ADyson

Comment: Thanks @YasirMushtaq for the addition to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change your Save `button` type to "`submit`" and remove the `<a>` hyperlink.
2. Use `<form>` as a part of both `modal-body` and `modal-footer` so the submit button will be part of it.
3. Take `book_id` in a hidden field so it will be the part of `POST`.

Look at the modal code below:

```html
<div id="editModal<?php echo $row['book_id']?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit This Book</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="updatebook.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['book_id'];?>">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="isbn" class="col-form-label">ISBN</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $row['isbn'];?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="col-form-label">Enter Book Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo $row['title'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="author" class="col-form-label">Enter Author Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" value="<?php echo $row['author'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Image URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="image" value="<?php echo $row['image'];?>">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description" class="col-form-label">Enter Book Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="description" value="<?php echo $row['description'];?>"></textarea>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="url" class="col-form-label">Book URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" value="<?php echo $row['url'];?>"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save">Save Changes</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```